# Header aligned to the left over center aligned paragraph

Tags: html, css

The title sounds really confusing but I drew a picture to try to explain:

[image: drawing of explanation]

I want to align my p tag to the center, and just above the p tag, I want h2 tag to be above the p but aligned to the left of it, I tried using padding but it doesn't scale correctly on different resolutions and aspect ratio's

so far what I have tried is

```
p {
   text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    padding-left: 48%; /* it's what worked with 1440p but not on 1080p */
}
```

The p and h2 are contained within a div

```
<div>
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <p>Text Content</p>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Center an outer div, and set the inner div to `display: inline-block`:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
   display: inline-block; 
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I want to align my p tag to the center, and just above the p tag, I want h2 tag to be above the p but aligned to the left of it,` how is this answering the OP?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph If you look at the illustration he provided, the `h2` tag should be left aligned with the `p` tag, not the viewport.